# What is wrong with my Linux installation if my script won't run with the following error messages

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-script, script

Trying to run some .sh scripts in a very cut down Ubuntu installation, but I'm getting messages of the following style:

```
./my_script: 61: [[: not found
./my_script: 61: ==: not found
./my_script: 61: ==: not found
./my_script: 61: ==: not found
./my_script: 67: [[: not found
./my_script: 73: [[: not found
```

There is obviously something not quite right :)

The script starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

## Edit

It runs ok if I start it like this:

```
bash ./my_script
```

## Edit 2

Sorry, that was a stupid question without some more explanation :) This script works fine, unchanged, on some RHEL machines - what do I need to change on the Ubuntu box to get the script to work, *without modifying the script*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `/bin/sh` a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`:

> $ cd /bin
>   $ sudo ln -sf bash sh

This switch may have unknown side effects, because changing this symbolic link makes `/bin/bash` get used for system script execution instead of `/bin/dash`.
. If you wish, you can always switch back to your original link arrangement.

Ubuntu customized their default shell a bit:

> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  801808 2010-08-10 15:58 bash
>   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   87984 2010-06-24 16:01 dash
>   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4 2010-10-16 21:58 rbash -> bash
>   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4 2010-10-16 21:58 sh -> dash
>   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4 2010-10-16 21:58 sh.distrib -> bash
>   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 2010-10-16 21:58 static-sh -> busybox

It's just a symlink anyway. If it breaks something you need change it back.

[Some users](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-499045.html) have been doing this since 2007 and have experienced little negative side effect. I might not call that insanity.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear - I need to be able to run the script without changing it - I am happy changing the configuration of the Ubuntu box however.

Answer (score 4):

The difference seems quite obvious:

- When you type **`bash`**, you execute **`bash`**.
- When you type `./myscript`, it executes **`sh`** (the `#!` line).

If the script uses `bash`-specific features, it should start with `#!/bin/bash` (or maybe `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear - I need to be able to run the script without changing it - I am happy changing the configuration of the Ubuntu box however.

Comment: @Rich: Create a wrapper that does `exec bash myscript "$@"`. There's no other at least remotely sane way.

Comment: your launcher script is a way better solution than mine if he won't be using a BUNCH of crossover scripts.  if he's looking for more interop in an enterprise type of setting, he might want to change his default shell back to bash.

Comment: @aking1012: Changing "default shell" will not affect `/bin/sh`, which stays the same.

Comment: I'm not talking about his default login shell, /bin/sh has just been a symlink to another shell on many linux distros for some time and almost all shell scripts point to it.  in this way it is a default shell...just trying to clarify